# Setting up Ant in windows

Tags: windows, ant

I am trying to set ant in my windows seven pc. I have followed the instructions correctly and everything is ok. I have even set ANT_HOME variable. However, when i run "ant" in command prompt, here is the error am getting.

```
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because there does not exist a build.xml file in the current folder, at the time you issue the command ant. 
Typically, Ant's build file, build.xml is located the project's base directory. However you are allowed to use different file names or use a build file placed in a different location.
Check out a tutorial like this on how to use ant:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ant/ant_quick_guide.htm